# Can't get a list of components installed on this host when installing a service on ambari

Tags: hadoop, http-status-code-404, ambari

I am trying to install a service on Ambari. but there is a step in the installation that fails. In this step, the installation script tries to get list of components installed on my host but it fails with error:- 
"Problem getting the list of components for host 'blabla'. Response code was: 404"

when i try to run what the script ran "http://blabla:8080/api/v1/clusters/BlaCluster/hosts/blabla/host_components" this is what i get in my browser.
{
  "status" : 404,
  "message" : "Parent Host resource doesn't exist.  Host not found, cluster=BlaCluster, hostname=blabla.  Host not found, cluster=BlaCluster, hostname=blabla"
}

how do I fix/workaround this ?

P.S. This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if there is something ambiguous, kindly note it out to me. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE-1:

- I am doing a single node installation remotely. I apologize for the ambiguity.
- While investigating, I found that when I tried to run the URL from the server itself, the following error is fired instead:

  "status": 403,
  "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
- The Ambari Verison I'm using is 2.1.0 on IBM's Open Platform (IOP).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the host in your cluster. Check the IP of that particular host and make sure you have configured your cluster using the same IP and all the */etc/hosts* file have same entries.

Comment: Thank You for your prompt response! I am performing a single node installation, so it is configured as my cluster. I have put more details as Updates to prevent further confusions.

Answer (score 0):

This was a server side problem, Contacted the support team and they fixed it on their end (nothing had to be done on mine)